# ConstraintLayout - proportional width/height to self?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to figure out how to achieve the following behaviour using constraint layout:

1. Place a view in the center of the ConstraintLayout parent
2. Make the view width to be half of the parent's width
3. Make the view height equals to its width

(i.e - place a square in the center)

I tried to use this combination:

```
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1"
```

But I'm not sure how to continue from here

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do without *Guideline* it is easy.

Just use **app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"**

It is work in version ConstraintLayout:**1.1.0-beta5** and later.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/dark_red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, when I copy and past this to the xml text editor, the preview shows that the square takes FULL width, instead of half width. I don't understand why. is it only happens for me?

Comment: @dor506 Trouble with version ConstraintLayout, my version `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta5'`

Comment: Oh I see. I'm using 1.0.2. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

To make your child's width be a half from parent's, use Guidelines: left one is 0.25 percentage, and the right one is 0.75

Then, place your view between those guidelines.

And finally, set layout_constraintDimensionRatio to '1:1':

[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline_left"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline_right"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Don't you think using 3 elements is overkill for such minor request? I would expect that it will be able to achieve this only by the view element and required properties

Comment: @dor506 Yes it is possible. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49648671/7825132

Answer (score 8):

I don't see why you'd have to use complex Guideline systems when you could also just use:

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
```

for half the width of the parent and

```
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
```

to achieve the same height as the width. This dimension ratio takes all numbers and even doubles.

Here is the entire code with center:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Upvoting for `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this behavior using guidelines([Constraint to a guildeline](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-to-a-guideline)). You should set two vertical guidelines with percentage (first - 25% & second - 75%) which will give you a half of parent's width. Then you should constraint your view to those guidelines by start/end. Also you should constraint it to parent by top/bottom and set your view's dimension ratio to 1:1 to make it square and centered.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```